# Is there any alternative way to achieve function of some gcc options? (like -Wlogical-op, -Wvla ...)

Tags: gcc, icc

I am trying to use `icc` to compile an already existing project which used to be compiled using `gcc`. At first I thought `icc` was compatible with gcc (my `gcc version` is `4.8.4` and `icc version` is `2015`) after reading [GCC* Compatibility and Interoperability](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/583823), but when attempting to compile my project with `icc`, i found some `options` `icc` doesn't support as below:

`-Wswitch-default`, `-Wredundant-decls`, `-Wcast-align`, `-Wlogical-op`, `-Wvla`, `-Wold-style-cast`

I wonder if there any alternative way to achieve the functionality of these gcc options.

Furthermore, is there a list of differences between gcc options and icc options?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Unsupported GCC options will be ignored by ICC during compiling. The options you listed are all about warning generation, which should not affect the compiling result. Have you tried compile your project by ICC? I think it will compile correctly.

Generally all  GCC projects can be compiled by ICC without modifying the compile options. But ICC projects may not be compiled by GCC.

I haven't seen a list, you could check their manual case by case when you meet problems.